# Error .load(), jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load a web page using jQuery and I receive this error

Webpage error details

Message: Permission denied
Line: 3517
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/js/jquery-1.3.2.js

And here is my code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#test').load('http://wwww.yahoo.com');

});

</script>


<div id="test"></div>
```

Thanks
Jean

[edit]

Some URLS do open, but the images are not displayed

Answer (score 0):

Check [this post](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html). It has a solution for your problem, but unfortunatelly you cannot do it in just JS because you must write a simple proxy to pass the requests out of your domain.

Answer (score 0):

You are using four Ws `wwww` in your url, use three of course:

```
$('#test').load('http://www.yahoo.com');
```

Comment: I corrected it, but still does not load, also if it was an error, yahoo would have the 404 page.

For some reason that too does not load

Comment: @Jean: i suppose you are not trying to load anything from a remote url, try loading local files to see if it really works also check to make sure that you have specified correct url to your jquery js file.